# Laravel check if installation meets all php extension requirements

Tags: php, laravel

The current Laravel 9 docs say you must install all of the listed requirements:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements

Now I ran into an issue, where one of those were not installed. So now my idea was to check, if those are all installed. I've looked at the `php.ini` file, but not all extensions are listed there. I have too little php know-how yet to check this out.

Isn't there a command that can be run to check if all requirements are met?

Comment: there is a script for Laravel 8 to check requirements under different PHP versions, might be helpful to get an idea how to change it to fit to Laravel 9: https://github.com/GastonHeim/Laravel-Requirement-Checker/blob/master/check.php

Comment: @NicoHood I would recommend you ask this (next time) on [sf] as it is more a configuration issue (question) than a coding issue (and you may get faster replies and better ones directly from SysAdmins)

Answer (score 3):

You can list all available php modules with:

```
php -m
```

This command will give you the full list of installed PHP modules/extensions. You can match this manually with the list provided in the laravel docs.

You can also get the php version from the command line:

```
php --version
```

Comment: This just lists what is installed, it doesn't know what Laravel needs.

Comment: Can't we find out the server requirements here and check what's installed?
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. With this you can always compare the two. Its not 100% magic, but enough for me for now. Maybe one could add `php --version` to also check the php version.